# Horizontal alignment of geom_text linked to emmeans and cld

Tags: ggplot2, text-alignment, geom-text, letter, emmeans

I ran a model on my data, thereafter using the emmeans function to do a Tukey post-hoc test, following by the cld function to add the compact letter display for significant differences.

```
    Mod1a <- aov(Drywt~Treatment*Soil, data=Pots1)
    Mod1em_split <- emmeans(Mod1a,~Treatment|Soil, subset=(Pots1$Drywt))
    Mod1cld_split <- cld(Mod1em_split, Letters=letters, reversed=TRUE, by="Soil")
```

After this I set up a ggplot to plot the emmeans as bars with the standard error bars and the cld as letters above the bars. The ggplot function uses the dataframe generated by Mod1cld_split directly. The letters are not horizontally aligned to the bars. No matter what positioning, nudging or hjust I try it does not align.

When I extracted the Mod1cld_split data to set up this Stackoverflow query I ran it through R and suddenly everything aligned perfectly. So the workaround is to export the data to a csv and use the data copied from the csv file in the ggplot call (directly calling up the csv results in the same alingment issue). But this is quite a roundabout way and I will need to generate a csv file for each plot I make and convert the data to R's format, which is unreasonable.

Is there perhaps a solution or another way to run emmeans and a cld (or equivalent) function on my model which can be used directly in ggplot? I should note that this problem persists regarless of the model used, I get this on all my data even in different R scripts and for different datasets.

For reference, the data and ggplot code which aligns is as follows:

```
Testdata <- data.frame(
  Treatment = c("CanolaHull10tha", "CanolaHull10thaTSP", "CanolaHull50kgha", "CanolaMeal10tha", "CanolaMeal10thaTSP",
                "CanolaMeal50kgha", "Control1", "Control2", "Manure10tha", "Manure10thaTSP", "Manure50kgha", 
                "TripleSuperPhosphate", "Willow10tha", "Willow10thaTSP", "Willow50kgha", "CanolaHull10tha", "CanolaHull10thaTSP", "CanolaHull50kgha", "CanolaMeal10tha", "CanolaMeal10thaTSP",
                "CanolaMeal50kgha", "Control1", "Control2", "Manure10tha", "Manure10thaTSP", "Manure50kgha", 
                "TripleSuperPhosphate", "Willow10tha", "Willow10thaTSP", "Willow50kgha"),
  Soil = c("Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", 
           "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", "Haverhill", 
           "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow",
           "Oxbow", "Oxbow", "Oxbow"),
  emmean = c(7.8925, 9.255, 6.6725, 8.67, 10.75, 5.5475, 1.03, 2.5975, 8.4175, 9.4825, 6.0475, 8.755, 7.335,
             8.9025, 8.1775, 4.3475, 9.1675, 3.676666667, 8.8, 10.9, 2.7975, 1.3075, 2.62, 9.7325, 12.61, 6.755, 
             9.4675, 5.4, 11.7175, 10.05333333),
  SE = c(0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.697872552, 0.604375358, 0.697872552, 0.604375358,
          0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358,
          0.604375358, 0.697872552, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358,
          0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.604375358, 0.697872552),
  CLDletters = c("abcd", "ab", "bcd", "abc", "a", "de", "f", "ef", "abcd", "ab", "cd", "abc", "bcd", "abc", "abcd",
                  "de", "bc", "def", "bc", "ab", "ef", "f", "ef", "abc", "a", "cd", "bc", "de", "ab", "ab"))

Drywt_trtVar <- c("Control1", "Control2","CanolaHull50kgha","CanolaMeal50kgha","Manure50kgha","Willow50kgha",
                  "TripleSuperPhosphate")
Drywt_subVar <- Testdata %>%
  filter(Treatment %in% Drywt_trtVar)
(Drywt50kg <- ggplot(Drywt_subVar, aes(x=Treatment, y=emmean, pattern=Soil))+
    geom_bar_pattern(stat="identity", position=position_dodge2(padding=0.2), colour="black", fill="white", 
                     pattern_density=0.05, pattern_spacing=0.01)+
    scale_pattern_manual(values=c("Haverhill"="stripe", "Oxbow"="crosshatch"), 
                         labels=c("Haverhill", "Oxbow"))+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=emmean - SE, ymax=emmean + SE), 
                  width=0.2, position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(Soil == "Haverhill", CLDletters, toupper(CLDletters)), y=emmean+SE+0.5),
              size = 6, position = position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust="dodge", check_overlap = T)+
    labs(y="Biomass yield (g) for chars at 50kg P/ha")+
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Control 1", "Control 2", "Canola Meal", "Canola Hull", "Manure", "Willow",
                              "Fert.\nPhosphorus"))+
    theme(legend.position="top", legend.justification="center", legend.key.size=unit(10,"mm"),
          legend.text=element_text(size=14), legend.title = element_text(size = 16),
          plot.title=element_text(size=18),
          axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, hjust=1, size=18, face="bold", colour="black"),
          axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_text(size=22, face="bold"),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), axis.line=element_line(colour="black")))
ggsave(Drywt50kg, file="Pots1_Biomass_50kgPha.jpg", width=12, height=8, dpi=150)
```

Comment: For anyone coming accross this, the issue I experienced was with the white spaces generated by the cld function in the letters (or .group) column. The workaround is to trim the white spaces both in the cld and the geom_text functions: ```Mod1cld_split <- cld(Mod1em_split, Letters=trimws(letters), reversed=TRUE, by="Soil") ```      ```geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(Soil == "Haverhill", trimws(.group), toupper(trimws(.group))), y = emmean + SE + 0.5), size = 6, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), hjust = "dodge", check_overlap = TRUE)+```